# Get foreign key value in Entity Framework 1.0 without Include method

Tags: .net, entity-framework, foreign-keys

I'm using VS2008 (.NET 3.5) and Entity Framework over SQL Server. I'm hoping to get the value of a foreign key column without using the `Include()` method to link up the table.

For example, the simple Author has many Books sample.

```
var book = context.Books.First();
int authorId = book.Author.AuthorId;
```

In this scenario, an exception is thrown, because Author is null. I'm looking to just get the author ID, but don't need the rest of the Author object. There is no `AuthorId` property on the Book class.

I'm sure there's a way to do this, probably by editing the EDMX directly, or maybe through the designer - any ideas how to get started?

Thanks

Comment: I'm surprised there is not AuthorID in the book entity.  Do you have the foreign key defined in the database?  If so, the EF Model generator should pick it up.

Comment: It's possible with EF4 to create entity links without exposing the foreign key property. The pro: the entity object is cleaner. The contra: You can't access easily the foreign key value

Comment: If I remember, EF4 includes the AuthorId, but EF1 (which is what I'm on) does not. All I have is the Author property, which is only populated when you call .Include("Author") on the object set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the FK value but it is not as straight forward. Each your navigation property representing single entity should have its pair property called `XXXReference`. In your case `AuthorReference`. This is the EF infrasturcture property holding your key internally. You can use similar code to get your FK value:

```
EntityKey key = book.AuthorReference.EntityKey;
EntityKeyMembers[] keyMembers = key.EnityKeyValues;
// Now each member of this array contains Key and Value property. Key is the name of 
// primary key property in principal entity and value is its value
// If you don't have composite keys and your keys are integer you can simply use:
int authorId = (int)keyMembers[0].Value;
```

Comment: Those assumptions are true for the project I'm working on, so it looks like this will work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this mentioned a few places, and it might be worth a look.

Extension method:

```
public static TValue GetId<TValue>(this EntityReference reference)
{
     if (reference == null)
     {
        return default(TValue);
     }

     EntityKey key = reference.EntityKey;
     if (key != null)
     {
         EntityKeyMember[] entityKeys = key.EntityKeyValues;
         if (entityKeys.Length > 0)
         {
            return (TValue)entityKeys[0].Value;
         }
     }

     return default(TValue);
}
```

In a partial class for your Book entity:

```
public int AuthorId
{
   get { return AuthorReference.GetId(); }
}
```